# How register IFilter with specifed message type in MassTransit

Tags: c#, .net, filter, masstransit

How to register MassTransit filter with specified message type?

```
 public class MyConsumeFilter<T> :
        IFilter<ConsumeContext<T>>
        where T : MyType
```

I tried do it like this but it's not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

You can register any filter type with the `UseFilter<T>(...)` method on a receive endpoint.

`endpoint.UseFilter(new MyConsumeFilter<SomeMessage>());`

Comment: i want to do it for all endpoints

Comment: `AddConfigureEndpointsCallback` within `AddMassTransit`